# TabHost onTabChangeListener - Setting up listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-tabhost, custom-adapter

I'm trying to change a few parts in my app. I can't figure out how to set up my app so each tab changes the data in my listview. Any help appreciated. 
My tab setup class:

```
public class WorkoutDaysActivity extends BaseActivity {

    ListView mListView = new ListView(this);
    ArrayList < CustomObject > w29w1m;
    CustomListViewAdapter mCustomListViewAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.workout_days);
        mToolBar = activateToolbar();
        setUpNavigationDrawer();
        w29w1m.add(new CustomObject("Squat", "65%", "6", "150", false));

        final ArrayList < CustomObject > w29w1w = new ArrayList < CustomObject > ();
        w29w1w.add(new CustomObject("Dead", "65%", "6", "150", false));

        final ArrayList < CustomObject > w29w1f = new ArrayList < CustomObject > ();
        w29w1f.add(new CustomObject("Bench", "65%", "6", "150", false));

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.TabHost1);
        tabHost.setup();
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("Monday").setContent(objects));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("Wednesday").setContent(objects));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setIndicator("Friday").setContent(objects));


    }


    private TabHost.OnTabChangeListener mOnTabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                mListView.setAdapter(mCustomListViewAdapter, w29w1m);
        }
    };

    private final TabHost.TabContentFactory objects = new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            return mListView;
        }
    };
}
```

customObject class:

```
public class CustomObject implements Serializable {

    private String exercise;
    private String percent;
    private String reps;
    private String weight;
    private boolean check1;

    public CustomObject(String exercise, String percent, String reps, String weight, boolean check1) {
        this.exercise = exercise;
        this.percent = percent;
        this.reps = reps;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.check1 = check1;
    }

    public String getExercise() {
        return exercise;
    }

    public String getPercent() {
        return percent;
    }

    public String getReps() {
        return reps;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
```

Adapter class

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ArrayList < CustomObject > objects;
    boolean[] checkBoxState;
    private CustomObject[] dataToBePopulated;

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtExercise;
        TextView txtPercent;
        TextView txtReps;
        TextView txtWeight;
        CheckBox check1;
    }

    public void addAdapterItem(CustomObject item) {
        objects.add(item);
    }

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList < CustomObject > objects){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objects = objects;
        checkBoxState = new boolean[objects.size()];
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return dataToBePopulated != null ? dataToBePopulated.length : 0;
    }

    public CustomObject getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.workout_item, null);
            holder.txtExercise = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtExercise);
            holder.txtPercent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
            holder.txtReps = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtReps);
            holder.txtWeight = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
            holder.check1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtExercise.setText(objects.get(position).getExercise());
        holder.txtPercent.setText(objects.get(position).getPercent());
        holder.txtReps.setText(objects.get(position).getReps());
        holder.txtWeight.setText(objects.get(position).getWeight());
        holder.check1.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);

        holder.check1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    checkBoxState[position] = true;
                } else {
                    checkBoxState[position] = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to set up my adapter to show the custom array lists Im making (w29w1m for example). Any help greatly appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to change the data inside the adapter, try changing the list that you've set on the adapter. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter. For example, if you've instantiated the adapter like `LVAdapter lvAdapter = new LVAdapter(context, list);` (or whatever parameter you use in your adapter), just change list to what you want the ListView to contain, then call `lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

But if you'd also change the adapter, try to set another adapter to the listview every time the tab is changed.

Also, I suggest making the tabSpec ids unique for each one.